# EEXIST: file already exists angular-cli buid

Tags: angular, angular-devkit

When I try to execute `ng build` in `-prod` mode with `--output-path` flag

I am getting this error **EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir**

Below mentioned are my Environment configurations

- angular/cli version 7.3.8
- angular-devkit/build-angular 0.13.9
- node 10.15.3 (npm 6.4.1)

I found this github issue [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15490) which refers to recent permission issue in transferring the built bundle folder to specified `--ouput-path` but the fix is made in angular 8 latest version.

Can someone guide me through to make the build work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `--deleteOutputPath true`. This will make sure the output path is deleted before building.

[See angular build docs](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to compile typescript and deleting `.build` in the project did the trick.